# Multiple Max Values

Tags: sql-server, max

I am trying to find multiple max dates. I tried group by but it only showed the max max date. I appreciate all your help.

```
MemberID    Contract    Group   Date
1   A   8   11/22/2016
1   A   61  10/19/2016
1   A   61  11/19/2015
1   A   8   7/26/2015
1   A   8   7/17/2014
1   A   8   7/17/2013
1   A   8   5/17/2013
1   A   8   3/26/2013
```

Ideal result would be:

```
MemberID    Contract    Group   Date
1   A   8   11/22/2016
1   A   61  10/19/2016
1   A   8   7/26/2015
```

Two Max Dates for MemberID 1, Contract A, Group 8.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: And how are we supposed to know which *max* date do you want?

Comment: Are you wanting the latest 2?

Comment: Yeah, what exactly are you wanting here? I can't tell from what you've specified. Why two for (1, A, 8) but only one for (1, A, 61)? What is your logic here?

Comment: @Jason no, because in that case it would have 2 values for Group 61

Comment: Basically I would like the max value of Group 8 11/22/2016 and the Max value of Group 8 (7/26/2015)  before member moved to Group 61.Thanks.

Comment: @Lamak I hope it clarified some things. I want the current max of Group 8, the max of Group 61, and the max of Group 8 before member moved to Group 61.

Comment: In other words, your question is REALLY about "I want to select only the rows that represent a TRANSITION from one group to another". Which is a very different question.

Comment: @pmbAustin You phrased it better. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this assuming you would be comparing other groups.

```
DECLARE @priorGroup int = 8; -- Just change these two
DECLARE @currentGroup int = 61; -- numbers to compare other groups

WITH max_Dates AS (
SELECT MemberID,[Contract],[Group],MAX([Date]) AS 'Date'
FROM Table_1
WHERE [Group] IN (@priorGroup,@currentGroup)
GROUP BY MemberID,[Contract],[Group])

SELECT *
FROM max_Dates
WHERE [Group] = @priorGroup
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 MemberID,[Contract],[Group],MAX([Date]) AS 'Date'
FROM Table_1
WHERE [Group] = @priorGroup
       AND
      [Date] < (SELECT [Date]
                FROM max_Dates
                WHERE [Group] = @currentGroup)
GROUP BY MemberID,[Contract],[Group]
```

Or you can try this one to have the dates on the same row

```
DECLARE @priorGroup int = 8;
DECLARE @currentGroup int = 61;

WITH max_Dates AS (
SELECT MemberID,[Contract],[Group],MAX([Date]) AS 'Date'
FROM Table_1
WHERE [Group] IN (@priorGroup,@currentGroup)
GROUP BY MemberID,[Contract],[Group])

SELECT MemberID,[Contract],[Group],
    (SELECT TOP 1 MAX([Date]) AS 'Date'
        FROM Table_1
        WHERE [Group] = @priorGroup
                AND
              [Date] < (SELECT [Date]
                        FROM max_Dates
                        WHERE [Group] = @currentGroup)
                        GROUP BY MemberID,[Contract],[Group]) AS 'PriorMax',
       (SELECT [Date]
        FROM max_Dates
        WHERE [Group] = @priorGroup) AS 'Current Max'
FROM max_Dates
WHERE [Group] = @priorGroup
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: Added another query if you are wanting dates on the same row.